# How do I get the kivy Window.softinput_mode = 'below_target' to move the TextInput box above the virtual keyboard?

Tags: python, kivy, window-soft-input-mode

I'm using python 3.8.6 and kivy 2.1.0.

When the text input box gets focus, the keyboard pops up and covers the TextInput box.  I've added the 2 lines below to force the keyboard to be below the target TextInput box, but it does not work as expected.

```
Window.keyboard_anim_args = {"d":.2,"t":"linear"}
Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"
```

I've also tried 'pan' and 'resize'.  The code runs with no errors, but none of these settings has any effect on the behavior, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but it's not obvious to me:-(.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  The full code follows:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import  Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.config import Config

Window.keyboard_anim_args = {"d":.2,"t":"linear"}
Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"
#Window.softinput_mode = 'pan'
#Window.softinput_mode = 'resize'

class ClearApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', spacing=10)
        self.txt = TextInput(hint_text='Write here', 
                             keyboard_mode='auto', 
                             size_hint=(.5,.1))
        self.btn = Button(text='Clear All', 
                          on_press=self.clearText, size_hint=(.1,.1))
        self.box.add_widget(self.txt)
        self.box.add_widget(self.btn)
        return self.box
    def clearText(self, instance):
        self.txt.text = ''
'''
if Config:
    _is_desktop = Config.getboolean('kivy', 'desktop')
    _keyboard_mode = Config.get('kivy', 'keyboard_mode')
    if _is_desktop:
        Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode','system')
        Config.write()
    else:
        Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode','systemanddock')
        Config.write()    
'''        
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode','dock')
Config.write()        

ClearApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use import Config before import App
which help you to focus and show your keyboard in the UI
for eg.

```
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App
```

use these these line in your code

Answer (score 0):

This function is available only in the master kivy version. so in your buildozer.spec file in the requirements put `kivy==master` when you are adding kivy to the requirements